# python telnetlib clear buffer

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this script that is telnetting into my router. I would like to use this script to save various show command output's. However it seems once I write the first command to the buffer I'm not able to clear that. For example in the script it writes the command "show isis adj" to a buffer then in the script I would like to run another show command and save that output as well. The problem here is it seems that the buffer is just saving the first command of "show isis adj" two times ? how can I clear this buffer so I can run multiple show commands ?

Also I did read some other stack overflow post and they reference using the "Telnet.read_until(expected[, timeout])" however I experimented with that some but still I was not able to get it to work.

```
import telnetlib
import datetime


now = datetime.datetime.now()

host = "x.x.x.x" # your router ip
username = "root" # the username
password = "root"


print("""#######################
  CONNECTING TO DEVICE""")

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
tn.read_until("Username:")
tn.write(username+"\n")
tn.read_until("Password:")
tn.write(password+"\n")
tn.write("terminal length 0"+"\n")


print("""#######################
  SHOWING ISIS ADJ""")

tn.write("show isis adjacency"+"\n")
tn.write("exit"+"\n")
output1 = tn.read_until("cmd")
print(output1)


print("""#######################
  SHOWING BGP SESSIONS""")

tn.write("show bgp sessions"+"\n")
tn.write("exit"+"\n")
output2 = tn.read_until("cmd")
print(output1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You print `output1` twice! Fix it and use `output2`.

```
....
print("""#######################
  SHOWING BGP SESSIONS""")

tn.write("show bgp sessions"+"\n")
tn.write("exit"+"\n")
output2 = tn.read_until("cmd")
print(output2)
```